# How can I compile a GUI executable with ghc?

Tags: windows, haskell, ghc, wxwidgets

I ported a little Haskell program I wrote from Mac to Windows. It's a GUI application (wxHaskell, compiled with ghc 6.12.1), so it does not need the command prompt window to open. It does so, anyway, so my question: What must I do so that the program starts without opening a prompt window first? Is there some ghc switch for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using wxWidgets with cygwin, you can avoid having a console window appear by [passing the `-mwindows` flag to the linker](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Cygwin#To_generate_Win32_applications_rather_than_console_apps). You can tell GHC to [pass flags to the linker using the `-optl` prefix](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.10.3/html/users_guide/options-phases.html#forcing-options-through), so you could try building with `-optl-mwindows` and see if that works.

I've done that before when building a Haskell SDL application on Windows, and it worked for me. I think the `-mwindows` flag is cygwin-specific though, and I'm not sure what your install of GHC might be using as a linker.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have access to GHC on Windows, but it looks like you need to tell linker to use "windows" subsystem. `ghc -optl-mwindows ...` may work.